# How to turn off Software Updater pop up notification?

Tags: 18.04, update-manager

Ubuntu 18.04.  Every time I run an `apt-get upgrade` cycle, a "Software Updater" GUI will pop up when it's done.  It doesn't seem to add anything to the process and is annoying, so I want it to stop existing.

How do I make it go away?  I can't find any settings for it.

Comment: Does `gsettings get com.ubuntu.update-notifier no-show-notifications` return false?

Comment: @PabloBianchi Returns true and I still get those popups...

Comment: @PabloBianchi can you try `gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier hide-reboot-notification true` ?

Comment: @AndreyArapov `No such key “hide-reboot-notification”`. Also, I'm not the OP, and that key doesn't seem related to its question.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod -x /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-updates-outdated`  (Also, what does Software Updater pop-up say?) ((you can ignore the `notify-reboot-required` since that was not your original post; but marking `notify-updates-outdated` script as non-executable is likely what you want)

Answer (score 11):

Try two possible options:

1. Disable from
   *Settings* -> *Notifications* -> *Software Updater*.
   Note there is also
   *Settings* -> *Notifications* -> *Ubuntu Software* with the same settings, I am not certain if it produces the same behavior.

   [image: screenshot]
2. At the command line, `gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier no-show-notifications true`.
   You can also set it via GUI with the very useful `dconf-editor` (you can install it if you don't have it).

Comment: The issue is in reference to the "Software Updater" GUI application that pops up when there are available package updates.  This will remove toast notifications saying that there are updates available, but it won't stop the Software Updater program itself from popping up.

Comment: That is not relevant to the question as this disables notification, but not the pop up

Answer (score 4):

> Remove update-notifier

```
sudo apt-get remove update-notifier
```

Please note that, this will remove only the graphic way to do system updates.. You can still do your upgrades using commands or Synaptic.

> Want To Disable/Remove Update Manager :

Open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the following command to disable the Update Manager auto notification on Ubuntu systems:

```
gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false
```

To re-enable the Update Manager auto notification, run this command:

```
gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch true
```

If you wish to remove the Update Manager package completely, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove update-manager
```

And to restore it again, run:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager
```

Uninstall update-manager
To remove just update-manager package itself from Ubuntu execute on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove update-manager
```

> Uninstall update-manager and it's dependent packages

To remove the update-manager package and any other dependant package which are no longer needed from Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove update-manager
```

> Purging update-manager

If you also want to delete configuration and/or data files of update-manager from Ubuntu then this will work:

```
sudo apt-get purge update-manager
```

To delete configuration and/or data files of update-manager and it's dependencies from Ubuntu then execute:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge update-manager
```

Please note that disabling Ubuntu Update Manager is not recommended. It is very important to update the Ubuntu systems at regular interval.

Comment: Warning! "sudo apt-get remove update-notifier" will remove the Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: It won't remove the whole Ubuntu Desktop. It will remove metapackages ubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-desktop-minimal, which is very useful to remember before upgrading distro version (recommendation would be to install them and update-notifier back again before upgrading).

Answer (score 3):

[How to turn off Software updater? (Xubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446395/how-to-turn-off-software-updater-xubuntu)

the answer given that unchecks the Update Notifier under "Startup Applications" is the one that I would use. I had to check "show hidden" to see it...

Answer (score 2):

I did not actually test this with 18.04 but as long as the UpdateManager python package present in the installation I suppose it will work.

In text editor with root privileges open UpdateManager.py

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py
```

In function **UpdateManager.start_available** (string  # 236) insert `return` statement, so as the result looks like:

```
def start_available(self, cancelled_update=False, error_occurred=False):
    self._look_busy()
    self.refresh_cache()

    return   # <<<--- added statement

    pane = self._make_available_pane(self.cache.install_count,
                                     os.path.exists(REBOOT_REQUIRED_FILE),
                                     cancelled_update, error_occurred)
    self._start_pane(pane)
```

Save the file and that will do the job.

Of course, you can easily revert it back by just removing or commenting out the `return` statement

I tested this with 21.10 and 22.04 although **UpdateManager.start_available** function body is slightly different there.

Hope it will help :-)

Comment: This is the only way (except uninstalling update-notifier) that worked for me.