# How can I get Ubuntu to stop notifying me of updates?

Tags: updates, update-manager

How can I get Ubuntu to stop asking me to update my system? I've tried two things in its configurations, dconf-editor and in the "Software & Updates", and clearly neither has worked.
[image]

Update:
Probably a duplicate of [How to turn off Software updater? (Xubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446395/how-to-turn-off-software-updater-xubuntu)

Comment: It's right there in your screenshot:  "Security Updates: Display Immediately"

Comment: Except I also have "no-show-notifications" on, and I can't disable security updates. The alternatives were worse. Also I have "check for updates" set to "never", so you'd think they wouldn't ever display.

Comment: To all voters for duplicate: this question is on disabling notifications for updates, not on disabling the updater.

Comment: Whatever makes that "Software Updater" pop-up go away and never come back is the solution for me.